# Can Plastic SCM server use a network drive?

Tags: network-drive, plasticscm

We are a few developers, working on Windows workstations, who have access to storage on a file server by means of a network drive (say X:). We cannot install any software on the server itself.

I was thinking of installing the Plastic server component on a workstation and configure the Plastic server to save to the X: drive. Is this possible?

A few SCM that I looked into have problems with network drives.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents it in the [administration guide](http://www.plasticscm.com/releases/4.1/manuals-html/en/adminguide.htm).

The only issue would be a greater latency for the server in accessing the data over a network drive, as opposed to accessing the same data on a local drive.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I previously went through the administration guide and also saw that no restriction was mentioned. I was kind of hoping for a confirmation that somebody tried this.

We would be developing on local drives and would keep the repository on a network drive. We can live with latency. But from experience with Bazaar, SCM programs can have trouble handling file locks on network drives because of latency.